# How to load BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a very simple question. How do you load BackboneJS and use it in a module without using requireJS?

I am only using 1 module, so all Backbone view, model and collection will be in that file.

index.html

```
<!-- libraries 10k zipped-->
<script src='js/libs/underscore-min.js'></script>
<script src='js/libs/backbone-min.js'></script>

<!-- modules -->
<script src='js/game.js'></script>
```

game.js

```
window.onload = (function(Backbone){

    var Input = Backbone.View.extend({  
            events: {
                'mousedown' : 'handleMouseDown',
                'mouseup'   : 'handleMouseUp',
            },

            handleMouseDown: function(){
                console.log('mousedown');
            },

            handleMouseUp: function(){
                console.log('mouseup');
            }
    }), 

    input = new Input;
    return input;
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass Backbone as the parameter since you're using it in the in params:

```
window.onload = (function(Backbone){

    var Input = Backbone.View.extend({  
            events: {
                'mousedown' : 'handleMouseDown',
                'mouseup'   : 'handleMouseUp',
            },

            handleMouseDown: function(){
                console.log('mousedown');
            },

            handleMouseUp: function(){
                console.log('mouseup');
            }
    }), 

    input = new Input;
    return input;
})(Backbone);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need a couple minor adjustments.

First, pull in `jquery.js` before `underscore-min.js` and `backbone-min.js`.

Then, you can use `$(function() { ... })` instead of explicitly assigning something to `window.onload`:

```
$(function() {
    var Input = Backbone.View.extend({...
    //...
});
```

Your `window.onload` has two problems:

1. You're using `Backbone` as an argument to the function but you're not supplying a value for `Backbone` when you call the function.
2. You're calling the function and assigning its return value to `window.onload`. `window.onload` should be a function, not a `new Input`.

If you really want to use `window.onload` then you'd do it like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var Input = Backbone.View.extend({  
    /* ... */
};
```

Your `<script src='js/libs/backbone-min.js'></script>` will give you a global `Backbone` so you don't have to `function(Backbone) { ... }` like you'd do with Require.js.

Also, if you're careful with the script order, you don't even need to wrap your `Input` inside a function, just leave this:

```
var Input = Backbone.View.extend({  
    events: {
        'mousedown' : 'handleMouseDown',
        'mouseup'   : 'handleMouseUp',
    },
    handleMouseDown: function(){
        console.log('mousedown');
    },
    handleMouseUp: function(){
        console.log('mouseup');
    }
});
var input = new Input;
```

in your `js/game.js` and you should be fine.

Comment: i am purposely not using jquery or requirejs because i am trying to keep the file size very small, but great advice!

Comment: @user1555300: You need jQuery or Zepto if you're planning on using Backbone views.

Comment: yeah, i found out as well when i couldn't create a new instance of view. thanks